# UibModal not passing angular.noop or undefined in function bindings when opening modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-components

Okay so I am using angularjs 1.5.8 and uibmodal to open a modal with a component inside the modal. I want to have the components be able to have some default functionality but also be able to override it from the consuming context so i'm trying to check if the consuming context has set that binding variable 'submit'. This works just fine when I add the component to my html and define the function in the consuming controller,

```
<contacts-form submit="vm.consumingContextSubmit(form, model)"></contacts-form>
```

but I'm not able to determine if the function binding 'submit' is set when I open the form via uibmodal.

If I'm going about this the wrong way feel free to suggest a better pattern.

I have the bindings for the component defined to allow undefined: (have tried with the regular old '&' as well.)

```
angular.
    module(APPNAME).
    component('contactsForm', {  // This name is what AngularJS uses to match to the `<contacts-form>` element.
        templateUrl: '../Scripts/components/add-update-forms/contacts-form/contacts-form.component.html',
        controller: 'ContactsFormController',
        controllerAs: 'cfc',
        bindings: {
            modelId: '=',
            submit: '&?',
            cancel: '&?'
    }
});
```

Here is the call in the consuming context:
    vm.$modalService.openFormModal('contacts', contactId, titleText, function(form, model) {
        console.log(form);
        console.log(model);
        });

Here is the service function opening the modal via uibModal

```
function openFormModal(modelName, dataModelId, titleText, submitFunction) {
        // convert undefineds to blank strings
        titleText = titleText == undefined ? '' : titleText;
        dataModelId = dataModelId == undefined ? '' : dataModelId;
        var templateString = '<div class="inmodal"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">'
            + titleText
            + '<button class="pull-right btn btn-danger" ng-click="$close()">X</button></h4></div>'
            + '<div class="modal-body" style="overflow:auto;background-color: white !important;padding:0px;">'
            + '<' + modelName + '-form model-id="\'' + dataModelId + '\'" submit="uib.submitFunction(form, model)" cancel="$close()"></' + modelName + '-form></div></div>';
        $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            template: templateString,
            controller: ['$scope', 'submitFunctionParam', function ($scope, submitFunctionParam) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.$scope = $scope;
                // all this should be unneed. 
                // it should be the same as vm.submitFunction = submitFunctionParam
                if (submitFunctionParam !== undefined) {
                    vm.submitFunction = submitFunctionParam;
                } else { // unneeded but to be explicit
                    vm.submitFunction = undefined;
                }
            }],
           controllerAs: 'uib',
            resolve: {
                submitFunctionParam: function () {
                    return submitFunction;
                }
            }
        })
```

But then when i'm inside my contacts form component:

```
function _submit() {
        console.log(vm.submit);
        if (vm.submit === angular.noop || vm.submit === undefined) {
            validate(vm.form);
            if (vm.form.$valid) {
                //do default updates
                var contact = vm.dataModel;
                if (vm.contactUrlId) {
                    vm.$contactsService.updateContact(contact).then(_onUpdateContactSuccess);
                } else {
                    vm.$contactsService.createContact(contact).then(_onCreateNewContactSuccess);
                }
            } else {
                vm.$alertService.warning('Form is invalid. Please fix errors.');
            }
        } else {
            //call function from consuming context
            vm.submit({ form : vm.form }, { model : vm.dataModel });
        }
    };
```

In my components I have a submit function defined that checks for angular.noop or undefined but i keep getting this function:

```
ƒ (locals) {
    return parentGet(scope, locals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm not sure exactly the mechanics so feel free to explain it and i'll mark it as the answer but just adding logic to where i build the template worked and passed in undefined as expected.

```
   var templateString = '<div class="inmodal"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">'
            + titleText
            + '<button class="pull-right btn btn-danger" ng-click="$close()">X</button></h4></div>'
            + '<div class="modal-body" style="overflow:auto;background-color: white !important;padding:0px;">'
            + '<' + modelName + '-form model-id="\'' + dataModelId + '\'" ';
        if (submitFunction === angular.noop || submitFunction === undefined) {

        } else {
            templateString = templateString + 'submit = "uib.submitFunction(form, model)" ';
        }
        templateString = templateString + 'cancel = "$close()" ></' + modelName + ' - form ></div ></div > ';
```